# How to retrieve the audio input and output device names in a Linux system?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, audio

I am working with Qt5 (C++) on Debian Linux. How can I retrieve the audio input and output device names of the system the program will run?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example inspired by the example in the documentation for [`QAudioDeviceInfo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiodeviceinfo.html):

```
#include <QtMultimedia/qaudiodeviceinfo.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // fetch info about all output devices
    const auto deviceInfos = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput);

    // display the audio output devices names
    for(const QAudioDeviceInfo& deviceInfo : deviceInfos)
        std::cout << "Device name: " << deviceInfo.deviceName().toStdString() << '\n';
}
```

Compiled with:

```
-fPIC $(pkg-config --cflags --libs Qt5Multimedia)
```

(`-fPIC` may not be necessary on your system. It depends on how the Qt libs were compiled)